# URL blocked: This redirect failed because the redirect URI is not white-listed in the app's client OAuth settings. Make sure that the client and web

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security-oauth2, spring-social-facebook

I am developing `spring-social-login` using `Spring Boot`. In this example, I have created `App` on the https://developers.facebook.com. When I am trying to login using the Facebook into my application, I see the below error comes. Why ??

```
URL blocked: This redirect failed because the redirect URI is not white-listed
in the app's client OAuth settings. Make sure that the client and web OAuth 
logins are on and add all your app domains as valid OAuth redirect URIs.
```

[image]

**Facebook login setting:**

[image]

And below is the **App Review** setting::

**Setting:**

[image]

[image]

**application.properties:**

```
spring.social.facebook.appId=970222193006255
spring.social.facebook.appSecret=27aae52935369b43710e6e8bacXXXXXXX
spring.thymeleaf.cache=false
```

**FacebookSignInAdapter**

```
@Service
public class FacebookSignInAdapter implements SignInAdapter {
    @Override
    public String signIn(String localUserId, Connection<?> connection, NativeWebRequest request) {
        System.out.println(" ====== Sign In adapter");
        SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(
                new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(connection.getDisplayName(), 
                        null, 
                        Arrays.asList(new SimpleGrantedAuthority("FACEBOOK_USER"))));
        return null;
    }
}
```

**FacebookConnectionSignup**

```
@Service
public class FacebookConnectionSignup implements ConnectionSignUp {

    @Autowired
    private UserRepository userRepository;

    @Override
    public String execute(Connection<?> connection) {
        System.out.println("signup === ");
        final User user = new User();
        user.setUsername(connection.getDisplayName());
        user.setPassword(randomAlphabetic(8));
        userRepository.save(user);
        return user.getUsername();
    }
}
```

**SecurityConfig**

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@ComponentScan(basePackages = { "org.baeldung.security" })
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private UserDetailsService userDetailsService;

    @Autowired
    private ConnectionFactoryLocator connectionFactoryLocator;

    @Autowired
    private UsersConnectionRepository usersConnectionRepository;

    @Autowired
    private FacebookConnectionSignup facebookConnectionSignup;

    @Override
    protected void configure(final AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.userDetailsService(userDetailsService);
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(final HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        // @formatter:off
        http
        .csrf().disable()
        .authorizeRequests()
        .antMatchers("/login*","/signin/**","/signup/**").permitAll()
        .anyRequest().authenticated()
        .and()
        .formLogin().loginPage("/login").permitAll()
        .and()
        .logout();
    } // @formatter:on

    @Bean
    // @Primary
    public ProviderSignInController providerSignInController() {
        ((InMemoryUsersConnectionRepository) usersConnectionRepository).setConnectionSignUp(facebookConnectionSignup);
        return new ProviderSignInController(connectionFactoryLocator, usersConnectionRepository, new FacebookSignInAdapter());
    }
}
```

**WebConfig**

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
public class WebConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

    @Bean
    public static PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer propertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer() {
        return new PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer();
    }

    @Override
    public void configureDefaultServletHandling(final DefaultServletHandlerConfigurer configurer) {
        configurer.enable();
    }

    @Override
    public void addViewControllers(final ViewControllerRegistry registry) {
        super.addViewControllers(registry);
        registry.addViewController("/").setViewName("forward:/index");
        registry.addViewController("/index");
        registry.addViewController("/login");
    }

    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(final ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addResourceHandler("/resources/**").addResourceLocations("/resources/");
    }
}
```

Comment: The red message tells you to add "localhost" to the domain setting of your app, did you do that?

Comment: yeah try to put "localhost" (no quotes) in the "App Domain" input box

Comment: Rc - I added screen shot which gives me error. Please guide now.