# App domains must match the domain of the Facebook Web Games URL (https), Mobile Site URL, Unity Binary URL, Site URL or Secure Page Tab URL

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-oauth2, spring-social-facebook

I am developing **Spring Boot + Facebook Integration** example. In this example, I've created an at app https://developers.facebook.com/. The screen shot of the created app shown below.

Also when I was passing the Domain name I am getting the below error:

```
App domains must match the domain of the Facebook Web Games URL (https), Mobile 
Site URL, Unity Binary URL, Site URL or Secure Page Tab URL. Please correct these
domains: localhost
```

[image]

I am using the same code mentioned in the [URL blocked: This redirect failed because the redirect URI is not white-listed in the app's client OAuth settings. Make sure that the client and web](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44477717/url-blocked-this-redirect-failed-because-the-redirect-uri-is-not-white-listed-i) .

Please guide and let me know if need any other details.

Answer (score 71):

1 - Click Apps and then select your app.

2 - Click the Settings button on the left side of the screen.

3 - In the Basic settings,
click the Add Platform button below the settings configuration.

4 -Select Website in the platform dialog.

5 - Enter your URL (localhost
works here).

6 - In the App Domains text input, add your domain that
matches the one in the URL.

7 - Save your settings.

[Check this link for detail](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/webhooks)

Comment: Also make sure the "Site URL" field at the bottom of the Basic Settings page matches the domain you enter in "App Domains" near the top. If one contains https, the other needs to also.

Comment: Did all that exactly, one line at a time. "Localhost" was accepted both in Site URL and in App domains. I could save my changes. Still getting `The method FB.login can no longer be called from http pages` in my console. God do I dislike Facebook.

Comment: referred link seems broken as on today

Comment: @RavinderReddy it is remove by fb this link may help you https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/getting-started/app-setup/

Answer (score 12):

You need to add the platform (website, facebook web games, android, etc.) your app is running on first. See [The explanation from Facebook](https://www.facebook.com/help/community/question/?id=589302607826562)

Comment: referred link seems broken as on today

Comment: It worked. I needed to add a website prior to add my website's URL into there.

Answer (score 6):

Add `localhost` under the Website > Site URL save and then add `localhost` in the App domain.

Comment: Thanks a lot this is really helpful

Comment: I need to add localhost and the domain.com for testing. How do I add both domains?

Comment: Did that, it was accepted and I could save my changes. Still getting `The method FB.login can no longer be called from http pages` in the localhost console.

Answer (score 0):

1 - Be in development mode

2 - In you facebook developer dashboard select the concerned app.

3 - Go to the Settings button on the left side.

4 - In the Basic settings, click the Add Platform button below the settings configuration.

5 -Select Website in the platform dialog.

6 - Enter your URL (localhost works here).

7 - In the App Domains text input, add your domain that matches the one in the URL.

8 - Save your settings.